# How to inhibit swipe-to-refresh when Toolbar is hidden and RecyclerView at the top

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I've got this layout setup in my app:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <ViewPager>
            <SwipeRefreshLayout>
                <RecyclerView/>
            </SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </ViewPager>
    </NestedScrollView>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm hiding the Toolbar on scroll down, to gain more space for my content. With a few exceptions when you fling/scroll with sudden movements in different directions, all works pretty well. The only problem is, as you can see in this gif

[image: SwipeRefresh issue]

that when the Toolbar is hidden, after swiping to the next month, a scroll/fling to reveal the Toolbar automatically triggers the pull-to-refresh of the SwipeRefreshLayout. I'd really like to inhibit this as a refresh potentially triggers a login with username/password/one-time-pin.

I've tried to subclass the NestedScrollView and consume the scroll/fling when a) the RecyclerView is at the top and b) the Toolbar is not visible but so far to no success. Any pointers on how to do this by the book?

Comment: The first you must to do is removing the NestScrollView from the ViewPager.

Comment: The viewpager is *in* the nestedscrollview, not vice versa, which is needed to make the coordinator layout work ... (As far as I know)